# How can we update or sync database assets table?

Tags: pimcore

When we modify image assets on pimcore.asset.storage, how can we update or sync database assets table?

We modified pimcore.asset.storage setting another folder but pimcore not refreshes new data on admin.

```
directory: '%kernel.project_dir%/public/var/assets/catalog'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not how it's supposed to work. The sync only goes one way from Pimcore to the storage, not the other way around.